# System crashes while playing specific games. How to diagnose and fix?

Tags: linux, windows, graphics-card, crash, gaming

I have asked about this already [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177651/skyrim-crashes-my-system-when-i-open-map), but since then it was reproduced with many other games and I really want to find a solution.

**Issue**

While playing some games my system crashes at some points.
Crash looks like some hardware issue: I can hear some zooming sound from the inside of the case (not loud, sounds like high voltage maybe?), screen goes black ("signal lost"), sound in the headphones starts looping. System does react only to hard-reset via reset on the case.

Some facts about this issue:

- It is reproduced in both Linux and Windows, DirectX and OpenGL (however now I use Linux exclusively)
- Never happened outside computer games
- Only some games are affected, for example it never happened in Dota 2 on both Windows and Linux
- In some affected games particular moment causes the crash (as mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/177651/skyrim-crashes-my-system-when-i-open-map): opening map in Skyrim, one campaign level in Red Faction Armageddon)
- Can happen after 3 hours of gameplay or instantly after launch, so probably not related to overheating
- CPU does not overheat, I monitor its temperature
- RAM also OK according to memtest
- List of the games: Bastion, Skyrim, Red Faction Armageddon, Besiege, Cities: Skylines (...maybe more)
- Not affected: Dota 2 (both Linux and Windows), Portal 1/2, Bioshock Infinite (both Linux and Windows), Battlefield 3, Crysis 3

**System specs:**

- Motherboard: ASRock Z77 Extreme4-M
- CPU: Intel Core i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz
- RAM: Kingston KHX1600C9D3/4GX DDR3 @ 1333 MHz * 4 (16GB total)
- Graphics card: Nvidia GeForce GTX 650 Ti
- PSU: 450 Watt PSU
- Disk: WDC WD20EZRX-00DC0B0 2 TB + OCZ Vertex 3 SSD 60 GB for system partition
- Coolers: 1 on CPU, 2 inside the case (front and back), 2 on graphics card

**Questions**

- How can I check what exactly causes the issue? I suspect my graphics card, can I check something without replacing expensive components?
- How can I fix this?

Comment: The programs that are not affected are all OpenGL programs.  The games that are affected are all Direct X games.  Can you provide at least one OpenGL program that is affected?

Comment: @Ramhound - Bastion, Besiege, Cities: Skylines were played on Linux, I think it is safe to assume that they use OpenGL (at least on Linux).

Comment: This sounds like one of the (many?) problems with Nvidia drivers.  Which driver are you using?

Comment: Run Furmark under windows for 4-6hrs, that'll stress test the GPU properly, if its hardware that'll show it. If it passes that, look at drivers.